# Why does the Android maps compass demo use a delegate for the SmoothCanvas class?

Tags: java, android, class, delegates, demo

In the Android MapsDemo available in Eclipse for the Google API, they create an inner class `SmoothCanvas` in MapViewCompassDemo.java. Within this class the re-implement seemingly every method and reroute it to a delegate instance of `Canvas`.

```
static final class SmoothCanvas extends Canvas {
    Canvas delegate;

    private final Paint mSmooth = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        delegate.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void setViewport(int width, int height) {
        delegate.setViewport(width, height);
    }
    ...
```

What is the point of the delegate in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `delegate` is passed in to `dispatchDraw`. The `SmoothCanvas` class is a wrapper around `delegate`. By delegating, the `Canvas` implementation passed to `dispatchDraw` does all the heavy lifting. The wrapper just allows the injection of the smoothed paint without implementing all the logic of `Canvas`.

Comment: Why did they not just override the few methods that use the Paint object? Like so: (there's more but there is not room to paste it all)

    static final class SmoothCanvas extends Canvas {
        private final Paint mSmooth = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

        @override
        public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top,
                Paint paint) {
            if (paint == null) {
                paint = mSmooth;
            } else {
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            }
            super.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
        }

Comment: didn't realize the indent doesn't work in comments:

http://paste-it.net/public/e4a86ba/java/

Comment: Delegation handles the case where the argument to dispatchDraw is not Canvas, but a derivative. Consider what happens if the Canvas passed in is already overridden to do something else: blur the bitmap, render in greyscale, etc. If you just supply you own overridden Canvas, you may loose functionality. By delegating, you use the original object, but with a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

The key point of delegating in that instance is:

```
private final Paint mSmooth = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

> > [`FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap%28boolean%29) bit. Filtering affects the sampling of bitmaps when they are transformed. Filtering does not affect how the colors in the bitmap are converted into device pixels. That is dependent on dithering and xfermodes.

By activating that flag, drawing bitmaps will basically increase its performance. You will in the example that `mSmoth` is used in every `drawBitmap` call.

Comment: How does that create the need to use a delegate though? I think you are answering why they created the `SmoothCanvas` class that extends `Canvas`. That I understand. What I don't understand is why they created the property `delegate` of type `Canvas` when they were already in a `Canvas` class?